# Old Wordpress install in subfolder of a new one

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I just installed a new Wordpress for a friend, and it works great.

He asked me to put his old version (Wordpress too), on a subfolder, and it have to be available.

The new wordpress : http://www.olivierpineda.com

The old one : http://www.olivierpineda.com/old/

My problem is on the old : the homepage works, but the other pages don't : it gives the 404 of the new install.

What I did :

- regenerate permalinks on old WP
- searched and replaced the old url for the new one in the db
- checked htaccess files
- checked if the links points on good permalinks for posts (it's ok)
- checked SO questions and answers

Nothing works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing I didn't know: the server was on **Nginx, not Apache**, that's why `.htaccess` rules were useless.

I have to change Nginx URL rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your htaccess.
You use old htacess. this is for root folder. and now site is /old folder 
Replace your code in old folder's htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /old/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /old/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sorry, I arleady did that.